# Fontsize in Gnuplot epslatex

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot, font-size

I would like to increase the size of the fonts in the x and y axis, as well as in the key. I do not wish to change the size of the image. Using epslatex in gnuplot, can anyone suggest how to change the font size ?

```
set terminal epslatex color size 7.0in,7.00in standalone
set out 'profile2.tex'
set xrange [400:600]
set yrange [150:280]
set size ratio 1.25
f(x)= -0.02*(x-500)**2+250
g(x)= -0.025*(x-500)**2+250
set xlabel "$x$"
set ylabel "$y$"
set key at 580,265 
plot f(x) w l lw 2.0 title "Initial condition"#, g(x) w l lw 3.0 dt 4 title "$\\alpha=0.025$"
set out
system('latex profile2.tex && dvips profile2.dvi && ps2pdf profile2.ps')
system('mv profile2.ps profile_TEST.eps')
unset terminal
set out
```

I have tried using

```
set terminal epslatex color size 7.0in,7.00in font '20' standalone
```

but the font remains unchanged

Comment: From `help epslatex` (scroll down): In standalone mode, the font size is taken from the given font size in the set terminal command. To be able to use a specified font size, a file "size<size>.clo" has to reside in the LaTeX search path. By default, 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt are supported. If the package "extsizes" is installed, 8pt, 9pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt are added.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `font ",20"` works.

[image]